# Dex file analysis, string_ The 16 characters after data are unknown for their purpose

Tags: java, android, dex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li4nv.png)I am currently trying to analyze the dex file, but I cannot find the answer to the data here and I am not sure what it is. I have consulted various materials.

```
package com.company.jvm;

public class Sample {
    public String m1;
    public String m2;
    public Object [] arr;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample.m1="22";
        sample.arr=new Object[12];
        System.out.println(sample.m1);
    }
}
```

It looks like a string_ The data in the item, but I am unable to explain it myself. Thank you for your help!

I have consulted a lot of information, but their analysis has overlooked this part. Thank you all for your help